# Trigger to prevent inserting appointments on Sunday, but in both cases the insertion is done

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think that the error is in `@dayName` - it might have the value null.
If it is not Sunday, I want to add this row to the table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_appointments   
ON Appointments
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);

    SELECT @dayName = AppDate
    FROM inserted;

    IF (DATENAME(DW, @dayName) = 'Sunday')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('No appointments on Sunday are inserted!', 10, 1);
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Appointments 
            SELECT * 
            FROM inserted;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: "I want to add this row to the table".  That statements means that you don't fully understand triggers in SQL Server, because the trigger can be called for *multiple* rows at the same time.  This is a very, very important characteristic of SQL Server triggers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a trigger.  Use a check constraint:

```
alter table appointments
    add constraint chk_appointment_date check (datename(weekday, appdate) <> 'Sunday');
```

Note that this logic depends on the internationalization setting on the server, but it is the logic that you are using.

An internationalization insensitive method is:

```
alter table appointments
    add constraint chk_appointment_date check ( (datepart(weekday, appdate) - 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 = 0);
```